# В чем разница между объявлением переменной и объявление с присваиванием?

Tags: java

В чем разница между этими двумя строками?

```js
int[] array1 = new int[];
int[] array2;
```

В первом создается объект типа int? еще такой вопрос: как может объект быть массивом?

update:

```js
int[] array2 = new int[] {1,2,3};
int[] array = {1,2,3}; //это аналогично первой строке?
//тут ведь никакого объекта не создается
System.out.println(array[0]);
System.out.println(array2[0]);
```

Comment: или int[] это как отдельный тип данных, тоесть объект получается типа int[]?

Comment: да, создается объект типа `int[]`

Comment: понял, вопрос исчерпан, спасибо =)_

Comment: тогда смысл создавать объекты-массивы, если просто можно использовать массивы?

Comment: Что значит "просто использовать массивы"?

Comment: @ebaklak вас вопрос про массивы не ясен, опишите подробнее

Comment: добавил, смотрите

Comment: смотрю видеоуроки Гоши Дударя, он использовал первую строку. Смысл? Если результат один и тот-же?

Comment: В обоих случаях создается массив. `{...}` - просто синтаксический сахар.

Comment: А вы не смотрите видеоуроки. Лучше читайте книги.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int` не как не может быть объектом, только если `Integer`.
Всё потому что, В Java всё наследуется от `Object`, кроме примитивных типов, как раз `int` является одним из 8 примитивных типов в Java.

```
        /* Так делать нельзя! Программа не пройдёт компиляцию.
         Вы создаёте массив типа int, далее с помощью оператора new
         вы можете инициализировать массив указав его размер.
         */
        //int[] array1 = new int[];
        int[] array1 = new int[1]; // К примеру тут происходит инициализация массива, размер которого будет равен 1
        // В этой же строке, вы опять создаёте массив типа int.
        // Но так как под него вы не выделили память, обратиться к нему вы не можете
        int[] array2;
        // Следовательно следующая строка выдаст ошибку.
        //array2[0] = 0;

        // В этой строке происходит выделение памяти под массив
        // который сразу же заполниться значениями
        array2 = new int[] {1, 2, 3};

        // Эта строка является сокращённым вариантом предыдущей строки
        // так как {1,2,3} по сути является массивом, по этому проблем не возникает
        int[] array = {1, 2, 3};
```

Если у вас возникают такие вопросы, советую прочитать какую-нибудь литературу по Java.

Answer (score 3):

1. Декларирование переменной + выделение памяти под неё. Можно обращаться к переменным.
2. Только декларирование переменной без выделения памяти. Обращение к элементам массива невозможно. При обращении возникнет ошибка компиляции.